# Setting Spark Properties on Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am pretty naive to development in Spark and Scala.

I am able to set properties at runtime on spark session using the config method like below -

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .config("spark.files.overwrite",true)
```

The above code will allow me to set properties on spark session level, but I want to set properties on a DataFrame level. Regarding this I have a few questions:

1. Is there any way using which I can achieve this?
2. If yes, will it affect the parallelism achieved by Spark?

Comment: Can you give an example - what configuration did you want to set per DataFrame, and *why*?

Comment: add some details to question like what you want to achieve on dataframe

Comment: For Example - I want my application to write two 2 output files, one with compression and other one without compression. Another example would be like, writing same file to 2 different locations varying on the basis of number of partitions.

Comment: DataFrameWriter can be configured when writing, see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Answer (score 0):

You can use different format (and using overwrite or not) when you write:

CSV with compression:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite")
.option("header","true")
.option("codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save(tempLocationFileName)
```

CSV without compression:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite")
.option("header","true")
.save(tempLocationFileName)
```